# reading a value from preferences

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

I have just recently implemented the inAppSettings kit. My goal was to load my default view and then add a navigation bar button item to the right called "settings". Once the user pressed the settings button it would take them to my settings bundle where they would make  a choice to which website they wanted, and then press back which would load up my default view once again with webview loaded once again with the new url.

I have implemented everything that I just described above but once the selection is made within the settings and the user presses back (aka dismisses the settings view to go back to the default view), the app crashes and I have no idea why. My code is below and if anyone knows why this is happening, it would be much appreciated. Let it be noted that once I run the app again after it crashes, the website loads correctly based on the settings they chose before it crashed.

P.S. the options the user can click to select are: Google, stackoverflow.

ERROR Message: Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[Upcoming settingsViewControllerDidEnd:]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x281c70'

Thank you in advance

```
- (IASKAppSettingsViewController*)appSettingsViewController {
    if (!appSettingsViewController) {
        appSettingsViewController = [[IASKAppSettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"IASKAppSettingsView" bundle:nil];
        appSettingsViewController.delegate = self;
    }

    return appSettingsViewController;
}

-(IBAction)selectSettings {
    UINavigationController *aNavController = [[UINavigationController alloc] initWithRootViewController:self.appSettingsViewController];
    //[viewController setShowCreditsFooter:NO];   // Uncomment to not display InAppSettingsKit credits for creators.
    // But we encourage you not to uncomment. Thank you!
    self.appSettingsViewController.showDoneButton = YES;
    [self presentModalViewController:aNavController animated:YES];
    [aNavController release];
}

-(NSDictionary *)intialDefaults {
    NSArray *keys = [[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects:kPicture, nil] autorelease];  
    NSArray *values= [[[NSArray alloc] initWithObjects: @"none", nil] autorelease];
    return [[[NSDictionary alloc] initWithObjects: values forKeys: keys] autorelease];
} 

-(void)setValuesFromPreferences {
    NSUserDefaults *userDefaults = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
    [userDefaults registerDefaults:[self intialDefaults]];
    NSString *picturePreference= [userDefaults stringForKey:kPicture];

    if([picturePreference isEqualToString:@"google"]) {             
        [self getUpcoming:@"http://www.google.ca"];
    } else 
    if ([picturePreference isEqualToString:@"stackoverflow"]) {
        [self getUpcoming:@"http://www.stackoverflow.com"];
    } else {
        [self getUpcoming:@"http://www.yahoo.com"];
    }
}

-(void)getUpcoming:(id) hello {
    NSURL *url= [NSURL URLWithString:hello];
    NSURLRequest *requestURL= [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:url];
    [web loadRequest:requestURL];
}

- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)webView {
    web.hidden=NO;
    [spinner stopAnimating];
    [load_message dismissWithClickedButtonIndex:0 animated:TRUE];
    pic1.hidden=YES;
}

-(void) loadMethod {
    load_message = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Loading..." message:nil delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:nil];

    spinner= [[UIActivityIndicatorView alloc] initWithActivityIndicatorStyle:UIActivityIndicatorViewStyleWhiteLarge];
    spinner.center = CGPointMake(135.0, 60.0);

    [load_message addSubview:spinner];
    [load_message show];
    [spinner startAnimating];
    [self performSelector:@selector(setValuesFromPreferences) withObject:nil afterDelay:0.0];
}

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
    UIBarButtonItem *settingButton= [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]
                               initWithTitle:@"Settings"
                               style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered
                               target:self
                               action:@selector(selectSettings)];

    self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = settingButton;
    web.hidden=YES;
    pic1.hidden=NO;
}

- (void) viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [self loadMethod];
}
```

Comment: TL;DR Can you please trim irrelevant code to make answering your question a little bit easier?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you implement the InAppSettingKit delegate? Add this to your current class above

```
- (void)settingsViewControllerDidEnd:(IASKAppSettingsViewController *)sender
{
    // dismiss the view here
    [self dismissModalViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    // do whatever you need to do
}
```